# How to display the AssignedTo field from a REST query?

Tags: rest

I am trying to display the `Assigned To` field in a table I am making with REST in SharePoint but all that is getting returned is `[object Object]`.  When I type this url into my website I can see the name of the person assigned to but it still does not show up in my table. Here is the code, all the other categories are displaying. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function LoadTasks()
{
    var call = $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Tasks')/items?$select=Title,DueDate,OData__Author,Priority,AssignedTo/Title&$expand=AssignedTo",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }

    });
    call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "aaData": data.d.results,
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "Title" },
                { "mData": "DueDate" },
                { "mData": "OData__Author" },
                { "mData": "Priority" },
                { "mData": "AssignedTo" }
            ]
          });
    });
    call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
        alert("Error retrieving Tasks: " + jqXHR.responseText);
    });
}
LoadTasks()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

AssignedTo in your example is a plain object (with `Title` property), not a string. DataTables probably tries to call the `toString` of the object, which will be `[object Object]`.

The best solution I can think of: **mData** should support deeply nested objects, so try `{ "mData": "AssignedTo.Title" }`:

```
...
"aoColumns": [
    { "mData": "Title" },
    { "mData": "DueDate" },
    { "mData": "OData__Author" },
    { "mData": "Priority" },
    { "mData": "AssignedTo.Title" }
]
...
```

If this does not work you could try to map `data.d.results`, like this (ES5):

```
var data = data.d.results.map(function(item) {
  item.AssignedTo = item.AssignedTo.Title;
  return item;
});
```